# What happens when a class/struct is returned WITHOUT RVO?

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, calling-convention

I understand RVO is desireable in general, but what happens when it cannot be applied? Specifically, how does the produced assembly code return a local class/struct instance to its caller?

```cpp
MyClass callee() {
    MyClass a;
    /* RVO is disabled */
    return a;
}

void caller() {
    /* RVO is disabled */
    MyClass b = no_rvo();
}
```

What does the stack look like in this case? Does `caller()` and `callee()` separately allocate space for `a` and `b` on the stack, then `a` is copied to `b`? If so, does the RET statement at the end of the `callee()` fully decrement the stack pointer to what it was before, or is the stack memory for `a` freed after the copy operation?

Comment: You can try it yourself on https://godbolt.org/.  Use `__attribute__((noinline,noclone))` so you can compile with optimization enabled and still see the function call.  If I get around to it, I might add an example to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the calling convention.  But all x86 32 and 64-bit calling conventions make the same choice, and pass a pointer to the return value as a "hidden" first arg.

`callee` can still optimize away `a` (unless something else stops that from happening) and just store directly into that return-value pointer.

non-trivially-copyable types may need to run the copy-constructor at some point, and a destructor for `a`.

---

But re: your actual question, with optimization enabled the caller would pass `&b` as the return-value pointer.

With optimization disabled, I think I've seen some compilers create space for a separate return-value temporary and then copy from there, which is hilariously redundant for trivially-copyable types.

In theory the return-value pointer could point somewhere other than stack memory, e.g. if assigning to an element of `static MyClass arr[10]`.

But it must not point to anything that `callee` could access any *other* way, because in the C++ abstract machine the return value is a separate object that nothing can be pointing to before the function returns.

Comment: Also, if the return value is a structure containing just a register-sized integer (or smaller) IIRC it's just put into rax on x86_64.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: oh yes, small structs up to 16 bytes are returned packed into RDX:RAX, in x86-64 System V.  Or if it's only FP vars, then packed into the low 8 bytes of each of xmm1:xmm0.  Or a `__m128` in the full xmm0.  Details *do* vary by calling convention there.  I forget what happens for non-trivially-copyable objects and whether they get special treatment.

Comment: That last remark is interesting. IIUC you are saying that the return value pointer cannot point to a, say, global variable, because then `callee` could not know they alias each other? However what if the compiler can analyze `callee`'s definition and find that the value is not used/read before the return value is modified?

Comment: @Acorn: oh yes, IPA (inter-procedural optimization) can allow many things that aren't safe in general, e.g. relying on a function not to actually clobber a volatile register.  ABIs / calling conventions have to work without that, and compilers do to when calling functions in libraries.  (Or without link-time optimization, any function in another translation unit).   But yes, you're understanding the problem correctly; that would be the kind of thing that would break.